# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jinput-linux, when running a my jar artifact

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm having some issues with a java project in which I use a gamepad controller, thrustmaster firestorm dual analog 3 (usb), under ubuntu 12.04LTS. I know the controller works under ubuntu since I can calibrate and test it. The problem lies on running the jar since I get the following error:

```
un 04, 2013 9:39:42 AM net.java.games.input.ControllerEnvironment log
INFO: Failed to load library: no jinput-linux in java.library.path

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jinput-linux in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1856)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at net.java.games.input.LinuxEnvironmentPlugin$1.run(LinuxEnvironmentPlugin.java:69)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at net.java.games.input.LinuxEnvironmentPlugin.loadLibrary(LinuxEnvironmentPlugin.java:61)
    at net.java.games.input.LinuxEnvironmentPlugin.<clinit>(LinuxEnvironmentPlugin.java:102)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at net.java.games.input.DefaultControllerEnvironment.getControllers(DefaultControllerEnvironment.java:159)
    at com.codeminders.ardrone.controllers.ThrustmasterController.initGamepad(ThrustmasterController.java:88)
    at com.codeminders.ardrone.controllers.ThrustmasterController.getGamepad(ThrustmasterController.java:79)
    at com.codeminders.controltower.ControlTower.initController(ControlTower.java:114)
    at com.codeminders.controltower.ControlTower.<init>(ControlTower.java:90)
    at com.codeminders.controltower.ControlTower.main(ControlTower.java:591)
Jun 04, 2013 9:39:42 AM net.java.games.input.ControllerEnvironment log
INFO: net.java.games.input.LinuxEnvironmentPlugin is not supported

No gamepad found!
No suitable controller found! Control disabled
Connecting to the drone
Using command port: 1500
```

I have created the .jar artifact with IDEA, and I think I have included all the libraries in the .jar, but even so, I get that error. I have also tried to execute my .jar like this

```
java -jar javadrone2.jar -Djava.library.path=/usr/li/libjinput.so
```

But with the same output... I believe that I have installed the jinput library, because if I type

```
:$ locate jni
...
/usr/lib/jni
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni/libatk-wrapper.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni/libatk-wrapper.so.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni/libatk-wrapper.so.0.0.18
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni/libgnomeproxy-1.0.0.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni/libpty.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni/libspawner.so
/usr/lib/jni/libjinput.so
/usr/lib/jni/liblwjgl.so
/usr/lib/jni/libswt-atk-gtk-3833.so
...

:$locate jniput 
...
/usr/lib/jni/libjinput.so
/usr/share/java/jinput.jar
...
```

What can I do to run my .jar??

Comment: Is there any typo in `/usr/li/libjinput.so`?, the output of the locate command does not list this particular path.

Comment: yes it was a typo  mistake there sorry, I've edited the post to correct it